# How to create Module DNN 6.0

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-5

I have created a module which have 3 fields(textbox) .Now I want to insert all these fields in Database table. So my question how to create table , how to make a connection and how to code related to insert, update ,delete and select data form that table in DNN 6.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may create table as your module installing. In the sql script file (01.00.00.SqlDataProvider), you can write sql scripts (like create table, create procedure, ...).

Also for your insert/update/delete/... you can use [linq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) or a controller which calls stored-procedures.

Check this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12853/Creating-a-DotNetNuke-Module-For-Absolute-Beginner) for more details.